# Installing Oracle jdk 11 on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, java-11

Recently oracle has changed their policy of license. I couldn't install oracle jdk 11 on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Can anyone please suggest any specific solution for that ? 
thank you

Comment: Oracle JDK 11 is identical to OpenJDK 11, just the license is different. On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you can simply install `openjdk-11-jdk` via apt (installs openjdk-11.0.4 at the moment). No need for extra repositories or manual installing deb files.

Answer (score 3):

I created a gist to help me address this specific issue: https://gist.github.com/Thoughtscript/d5cdba8013a006dbbd2899e899b95146

Partly reprised below. It took me a while but I got it to work with the OpenJDK-11.0.2 at the jdk.java.net link below.

```
NOTE It's recommended to download Java 11+ directly from Oracle. It's further recommended to use the OpenJDK 11.0.2 (and avoid other options).
See: https://jdk.java.net/archive/

sudo apt-get update
wget "https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz"
sudo tar -xzvf openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
sudo mv jdk-11.0.2 /usr/lib/jvm/

# Config
sudo nano /etc/environment

# Add the line below
# JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/"

# Config
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
# Add the lines below
# JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.2/
# PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bashrc

# Verify
echo $JAVA_HOME
javac --version
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which JDK you wanted, but here's a couple options:

If you want the closed-source JDK 11, [go to the official site and download and install the .deb file](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html).

If you want OpenJDK 11, [go to the official site and download the .tar.gz file](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11). Then [extract it to a location you want and set the environment variables](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-manually-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: I was trying to install Oracle jdk. After downloading the .Deb file, what would I have to do?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the `.deb` package from [Oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html)

2. install the package by double clicking on it.
3. Once it is installed set the JAVA_HOME in environment

   `sudo nano /etc/environment` and add the line `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1/"`
4. Add the configuration in `.bashrc`

`sudo nano ~/.bashrc` and add following lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11/
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

5. refresh the new configuration with `source ~/.bashrc`
6. enter he command `java-version` and you can see the version installed

   ```
               OR
   ```

Configurations in  (step 3 - step 5 )also can be done by using below method as well

Run command

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11/bin/java 2

sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

select the desired version from prompt if here are multiple java versions already installed and run following commands

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11/bin/jar 2

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11/bin/javac 2

sudo update-alternatives --set jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11/bin/jar

sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11/bin/javac
```